# Why don't these arrays match?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-4, phpunit

I'm trying to match array elements and I realized that even if the elements within the arrays are completely the same, they come out not matching each other.

First array:

```
  $json = '{ 
                "address1": "1818 Grove View", 
                "address2": "605", 
                "country": "USA", 
                "city": "San Diego", 
                "postcode": "91913",  
                "contact_name": "Natasha", 
                "contact_email": "nsr@yahoo.com", 
                "contact_number": "6198883849" 
             }';


    $data = json_decode($json, true);

    $address1 = $data['address1'];
    $address2 = $data['address2'];
    $country = $data['country'];
    $city = $data['city'];
    $postcode = $data['postcode'];
    $contactName = $data['contact_name'];
    $contactEmail = $data['contact_email'];
    $contactNumber = $data['contact_number'];

    $dataArray[] = array($postcode, $address1, $address2, $city, $country,$contactName, $contactEmail, $contactNumber);
```

Second array:

```
    $this->call('POST', 'address', array(), array(), array(), $json);

    $this->assertFalse($this->client->getResponse()->isOk());

    $decodedOutput = json_decode($this->client->getResponse()->getContent());

    $arrayOutputs[]= array();

    foreach($decodedOutput as $dOpt){
            $arrayOutputs[] = array($dOpt);
    }
```

To explain the code above, I'm using Laravel and I'm doing Unit testing. I'm calling a POST route to the address URI that passes the `$json` string and `$decodedOutput` receives the content and decodes it. I put all the elements within the `$decodedOutput` into an array called `$arrayOutputs`

If I var_dump both arrays, here's what I get:
1st Array:
     .array(8) {
       [0] =>
       string(6) "91913"
       [1] =>
       string(19) "1818 Grove View"
       [2] =>
       string(25) "605"
       [3] =>
       string(9) "USA"
       [4] =>
       string(9) "San Diego"
       [5] =>
       string(9) "Natasha"
       [6] =>
       string(19) "nsr@yahoo.com"
       [7] =>
       string(8) "6138883849"
     }

2nd Array:
          array(10) {
       [0] =>
       array(0) {
       }
       [1] =>
       array(1) {
         [0] =>
         int(74)
       }
       [2] =>
       array(1) {
         [0] =>
         string(6) "91913"
       }
       [3] =>
       array(1) {
         [0] =>
         string(6) "1818 Grove View"
       }
       [4] =>
       array(1) {
         [0] =>
         string(25) "605"
       }
       [5] =>
       array(1) {
         [0] =>
         string(9) "USA"
       }
       [6] =>
       array(1) {
         [0] =>
         string(9) "San Diego"
       }
       [7] =>
       array(1) {
         [0] =>
         string(9) "Natasha"
       }
       [8] =>
       array(1) {
         [0] =>
         string(19) "nsr@yahoo.com"
       }
       [9] =>
       array(1) {
         [0] =>
         string(8) "6198883849"
       }
     }

Now obviously there looks like there are some differences in formatting, but they're both still arrays. So next thing I did was to check if they really are different:

```
 if($arrayOutputs[2] === $dataArray[0])
    {
        echo "Match";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Doesn't Match";
    }
```

I took two elements from each array that I know have the same elements, and when I run the code, I always end up getting that they don't match. Why are they different?

Comment: from output, it seems like second array element is another array. Have you try to print those elements (exactly those,not whole array) or at least use gettype for them?

Comment: @FuzzyTree I'm not actually trying to check if the one array matches the other. I'm actually trying to compare specific elements within each array.

Comment: Sorry, but the way you construct that array is simply an *Oh God Why?!* moment. Your many lines of repetitive code do mostly the same as simply this: `$dataArray[] = array_values($data);`

Comment: === check also type. array itself cant be the same as element inside array.

Comment: @BojanKovacevic I just did a gettype() and they both come out as string(5) "array"
string(5) "array"

Comment: @deceze No offense taken. I'm a new developer and I'm taking in as much constructive criticism as I can to better myself. As I was writing this code, I actually told myself that "this look all too repetitive" but it only got that way because I was getting error about Undefined offsets so I started to mess around with the code to figure out the problem.

Comment: post code with gettype,it doesnt look like that from array input. also what does echo $arrayOutputs[2] print?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$arrayOutputs[2]` is an array itself

```
if($arrayOutputs[2][0] === $dataArray[0])
                   ^^^ add this
```

Comment: Perfect. Got it to match.

Answer (score 2):

When building your second array, replace

```
foreach($decodedOutput as $dOpt){
    $arrayOutputs[] = array($dOpt);
}
```

with

```
foreach($decodedOutput as $dOpt){
    $arrayOutputs[] = $dOpt;
}
```

Comment: this is the right answer as it fixes the real problem